# C string interpolation

Tags: c, string

I'm building simple http status checker in C. I've got the network part done, but I'm having trouble with string manipulation. Here how it works:

```
$ ./client http://domain.com/path.html#anchor
200
```

This utility simply outputs the status of given page on the command line. I need to parse the given string into hostname and request path. I've also built a "template" string with this define:

```
#define HTTP_GET_MSG "GET %s HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent: my-agent-0.01\nHost: %s\n\n"
```

I'd like to know how should I approach the interpolation of parsed url (host and path) into this defined string before `send()`ing it to the socket?

Comment: You should know that line endings in the HTTP protocol are `\r\n`, not simply `\n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple approach is to use sprintf:

```
char req[ SOME_SUITABLE_SIZE ];
sprintf( req, HTTP_GET_MSG, host, path );
```

but this will be vunerable to buffer overruns unless you check the lengths of "host" and "path" beforehand. If your system has [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) you can avoid this:

```
snprintf( req, SOME_SUITABLE_SIZE, HTTP_GET_MSG, host, path );
```

Comment: this will work. I'll just have to calculate the total `req` size beforehand. Thanks!